# SQL query doesn't work on SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am new to web services and I have written some simple queries. They work just fine, but this one doesn't return json

```
SqlDataReader dr;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE address LIKE %@add%", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", address);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If I type it like

```
"select * from doctors WHERE address = @add
```

it works fine

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `like '%' + @add + '%'`

Comment: Wrap %@add% inside single quotes

Comment: @ganeshran That won't work since `@add` is a parameter.  The OP needs to do what Alex has.

Comment: You have to add the wildcards like Alex said or add them to `address` before creating the parameter.

Comment: what is ```address```?  Is it a string or an object?

Comment: @juharr oh ok thanks.

Comment: ty alex that works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Add the % to the value, not the parameter name

```
var address = "%1 main street%";

SqlDataReader dr;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE address LIKE @add", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", address);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SqlDataReader dr;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE address LIKE '%@add%'", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", address);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```